# Eclipse 2021-09 removed "Check for Updates" menu item

Tags: eclipse

i've just updated from Eclipse 2021-06 to 2021-09 and suddenly the "Check for Updates" part, as also everything related to the Marketplace in the Help menu is gone:

[Check for Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRe8w.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

/e: The issue were some deleted ui plugins after trying to update Eclipse without administrator rights. Those seemed so be responsible for updating Eclipse, also possible solutions such as e.g.: https://askubuntu.com/questions/474160/install-new-software-button-disappeared-from-eclipse didn't worked for me. The only solution for me was to reinstall Eclipse...

Comment: It is still there on my 2021-09. Look at the "Menu Visibility" tab of "Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective" where it can be turned on/off.

Comment: What greg-449 says. Probably, _Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective..._ should fix it. Ctrl+3 and typing `Check for Updates` should work independent whether the menu item is shown or not.

Comment: *How* did you update from Eclipse 2021-06 to 2021-09?

Comment: Hey @nitind, i was using the "Check for Updates" button in a time, where it was still available with 2021-06 :) But i did this without administrator rights, so this seemed to mess a few things up as a part of it might had write access and a part not. After a restart it was showing me "2021-09", but without the functionality to update, use the marketplace or install new software.

Comment: @theraven Do not run Eclipse as administrator. If you did it, do a fresh installation.